# Need handler for worker timeout

Tags: gunicorn

I need to be able to do follow-up processing if gunicorn reports a worker timeout and "murders" the worker. It looks like worker_exit is only called if the worker process had crashed, but not if it is unresponsive. How do I figure out whether one or more workers are timing out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figure out this is the solution:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

I would just need to set an alarm signal where I suspect there could be a timeout.